# Problem solving - Money division among persons

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, education

I am trying to solve the following problem (from this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415502233)).

I have tried several ways using fractions and proportions with no success. I really miss the point here, and I am not able to logically solve it.

I kindly ask you if you could provide me some tips/guidelines/steps how to solve it, I really would like to understand the logic behind the solution.

The problem:

> A man divides 1622,50 EUR among four persons so that the first has 40
>   EUR more that the second, the second 60 EUR more then the third, and
>   the third 87.50 EUR more than the fourth. How much did the fourth
>   person receive? The solution is 300 EUR.

In case this question is not appropriate here, please let me know I can move it to different stack exchange site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create linear equations for these

Let $a, b, c, d$ be the amounts that these four people have respectively. Now,

$$c = d + 87.50$$
$$b = c + 60$$
$$b = d + 87.50 + 60$$
$$a = b + 40$$
$$a = d + 87.50 + 60 + 40$$
$$a + b + c + d = 1622.50$$
$$d + 87.50 + 60 + 40 + d + 87.50 + 60 + d + 87.50 + d = 1622.50$$
$$ 4d + 422.5 = 1622.5 $$
$$ 4d = 1200 $$
$$ d = 300 $$

Comment: how do you calculate the line before the last line?

Comment: @Radex Updated the answer

Comment: thanks I appreciate it